# Static 3D Environment Map for localization and path planning

Tags: path-planning, octomap, 3d-navigation, octomap-mapping, localilzation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working on a robotics project that involves building a 3D static environment map. I am considering Octomap as a possible solution. The 3D map
needs to be generated with some process and then utilized for localization and path planning. The 3D map is simple; it is not a complex terrain. The map also contains obstacles. Can someone advise me on how and why to use Octomap? Is it worth the time
so that I can incorporate localization and path planning? Please comment on complexity if possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54710/static-3d-environment-map-for-localization-and-path-planning/) by [Ash420](https://answers.ros.org/users/4158/ash420/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can build a static map with a 3D modelling tool (e.g. Blender, Sketchup) and then convert it to OctoMap, as detailed in these instructions:
https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/wiki/Importing-Data-into-OctoMap

There are multiple examples of path planning in OctoMap, check out the following two publications:

- [Real-Time Navigation in 3D Environments Based on Depth Camera Data](http://hrl.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/maierd12humanoids.pdf) [(Video)](http://youtu.be/srcx7lPoIfw)
- [Navigation in Three-Dimensional Cluttered Environments for Mobile Manipulation](http://hrl.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/hornung12icra_3Dnav.pdf) [(Video)](http://youtu.be/XzkC4Ez8GYE)

Code for 6D localization in octomap is already available in the [humanoid_localization stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/humanoid_localization), with details in the paper [Humanoid Robot Localization in Complex Indoor Environments](http://hrl.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/hornung10iros.pdf) [(Video)](http://youtu.be/uiIi2rSKWAU)

You won't get a plug-and-play solution in terms of complexity (you will probably have to read and adjust some code), but in general that has all been done before. As on why to use OctoMap: You will have a memory-efficient 3D occupancy map representation. If you environment is only small and the memory footprint does not matter, you will still have an integrated solution with most code already implemented (map building, raycasting for localization, efficient map access).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3